# how to get username and password from restful-API from json format into laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel-5.4

i don't  have more experience in API. i am using laravel 5.4 version. where i self create registration API into Restful-API. i am sending request into android phone but can't get its value into laravel5.4. so please tell me how can i get it. with explanation ...
Please Note that user name and password is into json format.. sample is give below...

```
{
    "arg": {
        "username": "410",
        "emailID": "password",
        "phoneNumber": "+91XXXX98"
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that i am not using token based authentication  and i don't want to use this.. please give me a simple easiest way for access this .

Comment: Why in the would you explicitly choose _not_ to handle passwords securely? I hope this is not some app you're gonna let other people use (at least without a big notification about putting their credentials at risk).

Comment: ok thanks ,, not right now... have you any answer.